# How to square and sum only positive integers in array without using loop or comprehension?

Tags: python

Here is my array :

```
[3, -1, 1, 14]
```

I want to square only positive elements and sum them **without using any loop or list / set / dictionary comprehension**. However standard library packages can be used.

Note:-*The elements in list can rage between -100 to +100*

i think recursion can be use to move through  list, but it will be quite a bit less efficient. It can also fail on long lists, when Python hits the system recursion limit (which is 1000, by default).

Comment: Why no for-loop or list comprehension? They are basic language constructs that you'd find in any python codebase. No "for loops" you can try `sum(map(lambda x: x*x if x>0 else 0, l))`, `l` is your list.

Comment: You wouldn't additionally name comprehensions if you considered them loops, so... generator expression is the obvious and allowed solution.

Comment: Can you use numpy (which is a popular Python library) i.e. : `import numpy as np; arr = np.array([3,-1,1,14]); print(np.square(arr[arr > 0]).sum());`

Comment: numpy ia a third party library

Comment: @Ch3steR thanks for the input however the expression you gave takes sometime, is there a way to await it like we do in javascript?

Comment: range  of integers,will be between -100 to 100, it will be all int

Comment: @JatinMehrotra If you say it takes "sometime" how much time do you mean? The sum of a list with 100.000 entries should be computed in fractions of a second on a "normal" computer.

Comment: I can't think of any solution that would work for ints but not floats or complex numbers etc.

Comment: @syntaxfree Think of counting, either with a `Counter` (where ints mean that there are at most 201 entries, so with large lists this could be efficient) or with a list (which needs ints as indices (although without loops, that's probably no good anyway)).

Answer (score 2):

List comprehensions can be seen as syntactic sugar for functions that take functions such as `map`, `filter` and `reduce`. For example:

```py
[f(x) for x in xs]
```

is the same as

```py
list(map(f,xs)
```

and

```py
[x for x in xs if x>0]
```

is identical to

```py
list(filter(lambda x:x>0, xs))
```

Ch3steR's answer in the comments above is

```py
sum([x*x if x>0 else 0 for x in xs])
```

The sugar-less equivalent of this is

```
xs = [3,-1,1,14]
sum(map(lambda x: x*x if x>0 else 0, xs))
```

Maybe for clarity we can remove lambdas:

```py
def square_if_pos(x):
    if x>0:
        return x*x
    if x<=0:
        return 0

xs = [3,-1,1,14]
answer = sum(map(square_if_pos, xs))
```

Another valid answer with list comprehensions would be

```py
sum([x*x for x in xs if x>0])
```

which, without the syntax sugar is equivalent to

```py
answer = sum(map(square_if_pos,filter(lambda x:x>0, xs))))
```

or maybe without so many parentheses:

```
positive_numbers = filter(lambda x: x>0, xs)
positive_squares = map(lambda x: x*x, positive_numbers))
answer = sum(positive_squares)
```

Both answers are equivalent because summing a list with some zeros or removing those zeros is the same thing: x+0 == x. Maybe for long enough lists, the solution with `filter` is more efficient.

---

*Edit: I had misunderstood a comment above as being a full answer*

Answer (score 2):

You could use reduce from functools:

```
from functools import reduce

L = [3, -1, 1, 14]

R = reduce(lambda a,b:a+b*b*(b>0),L,0)

print(R) # 206
```

If the "them" in "I want to square only positive elements and sum them" refers to all numbers (not only the squared one), you can write it like this:

```
R = reduce(lambda a,b:a+b*b**(b>0),L,0)

print(R) # 205
```

Answer (score 1):

I mean it is not the most efficient, but it surely works with recursion:

```
def sum_and_square(arr, left, right):
    if left == right:
        if arr[left]>0:
            return arr[left]**2
        else:
            return 0;
    
    mid = int(left + (right-left) / 2)
    return sum_and_square(arr, left, mid) + sum_and_square(arr, mid+1, right)
    
l = [1, 2, -3, -4] * 1000000
sum_and_square(l, 0, len(l)-1)
```

Comment: is there a limit with recursion in python?

Comment: Google says 1000 is the limit in depth, but the depth with this approach is `log(n)` I think. So, you will not hit that limit, but it gets slow with large numbers of course.

Answer (score 1):

**Poster: "i think recursion can be use to move through list, but it will be quite a bit less efficient."**

Actually, this issue can be solved by using recursion by reducing the list size by half at each recursion rather than 1.

```
def sum_square(x):
    if not x:
        return 0
    if len(x) == 1:
        return x[0]*x[0] if x[0] > 0 else 0
    
    # Split array in half, and recurse on two halves
    # This limits recursion depth for list of length n to log2(n)
    # rather than n
    n = len(x) // 2
    return sum_square(x[:n]) + sum_square(x[n:])
```

**Test**

Test 1: Posted List

```
a = [3,-1,1,14]
>>> sum_square(a)
206
```

Test 2: large list

```
from random import randint

# Create large list
a = [randint(-100, 100) for _ in range(10000000)]

>>>sum_square(a)
169445030
```

Answer (score 0):

As you were told not to use loops and sum a list, there is no other way than use streams with functional tools that are built in python

Use `map(func, *iterables)` to compute the sum for a given list

As far as you want to square only positive numbers your function will look like

```
def square(x: int):
    if x > 0:
        return x * x
    else:
        return 0
```

Or you can rewrite that as a lambda function with ternary operator

```
lambda x: x * x if x > 0 else 0
```

Then map function will look like this

```
map(lambda x: x * x if x > 0 else 0, arr)  # [9, 0, 1, 196]
```

And then use `sum(*iterable)` function to sum up the result of an array

```
sum(map(lambda x: x * x if x > 0 else 0, arr))
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you didn't rule out generator expressions:

```
sum(x * x for x in xs if x > 0)
```

Comment: This is a gotcha. OP says "can we do it like in javascritpt", too.

Comment: @syntaxfree No idea what either of your sentences mean. Please clarify.

Comment: @syntaxfree Still wondering what you mean...

Answer (score -1):

Consider that (what follows is math and by ^ I mean power, which is `**` in Python)

```
x^2 + y^2 == (x+y)^2 - 2*x*y
```

and

```
(x+y+z)^2 = ((x+y)+z)^2 = x^2 + 2xy + y^2 + 2*(x+y)*z + z^2
```

by induction it can be shown that

```
(x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n)^2 = 2*x_1 x_2 + 2*(x_1+x_2)*x_3 + ... 2*(x_1+...x_n)*x_n + x_1^2 + ... + x_n^2
```

Then the sum of squares is the square of the sum plus twice the following

```
x_1*x_2 + (x_1+x_2)*x_3 + (x_1+... x_n)*x_n
```

So what we need to do is accumulate the partial sums `x_1`, `x_1+x_2`, etc. in a list and then "zip with" the elements of the list itself.

Let's make this Python again.

```py
from itertools import accumulate

def square(x):
    return x*x
def plus(x,y):
    return x+y
def times(x,y):
    return x*y


xs = [3, 1, -1, 14]
xs = list(filter(lambda x: x>0, xs)) # I wish we could avoid this so early

# either this or change square to lambda x:x*x if x>0 else 0
squared_sum = square(sum(xs))
partial_sums = accumulate(xs, plus)
missing_part = 2*sum(map(times, partial_sums, xs[1:]))

answer = squared_sum - missing_part
```

and there you have it. (I'm still hoping for an algebraic solution that avoids having to filter the list, though.)

Comment: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71APNKT73EL.jpg